# After updating CPU-Z through winget, the language became chinese

Tags: windows-11, package-management, cpu-z

I installed CPU-Z before and it was english. Then discovered winget today. Expecting it will behave close to APT on Debian-based operating systems, I upgraded all of the softwares installed on my machine. One of those is CPU-Z which I previously installed, and was in english.

I tried invoking `winget install` for the CPU-Z adding the parameter --locale=us-EN but it does not recognize the parameter.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? [The behavior you describe is intended.](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/238).  You will have to change the display language of Windows to get CPU-Z installed in English

Comment: @Ramhound I did not used or even installed any chinese language on my Windows 11. I only installed two languages and both are english variants(US and Philippines). Even my Microsoft account is set to en-PH.

Comment: I don’t know what to say. The language of the package with regards to Winget is exclusively connected to the languages packages installed on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound it should have been. I installed Windows 11 from scratch instead of upgrading from 10.

Comment: There is no difference between a clean installation and an upgrade install except for a single registry key and the fact you keep your files. Other than those two differences they are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the application through the Control Panel and tried to reinstall it through winget using this command `winget install --id=CPUID.CPU-Z  -e`, and it worked.